# Insert missing date and fill selected columns with existing values but keep one column as NA in R

Tags: r

I have data data set below... as you can see some months are missing (my data frame should be quarterly).  I need to add the missing latest two quarters 2020-04-01 and 2020-07-01.. but the columns GEO, NAICS, shoule repeat the existing variables.  ONLY NA should be filled in the VALUE column.  Is there a way of doing this?  I am using the following code, but it is not working...

| REF_DATE | GEO | NAICS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | AB | fishin | 33 |
| 2020-01-01 | AB | mining | 233 |
| 2020-01-01 | AB | constr | 53 |
| 2020-01-01 | BC | fishin | 353 |
| 2020-01-01 | BC | mining | 253 |
| 2020-01-01 | BC | constr | 953 |
| 2020-10-01 | AB | fishin | 33 |
| 2020-10-01 | AB | mining | 293 |
| 2020-10-01 | AB | constn | 343 |
| 2020-10-01 | BC | fishin | 633 |
| 2020-10-01 | BC | mining | 363 |
| 2020-10-01 | BC | constr | 523 |

I should have these data inserted

| REF_DATE | GEO | NAICS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-01 | AB | fishin | NA |
| 2020-04-01 | AB | mining | NA |
| 2020-04-01 | AB | constr | NA |
| 2020-04-01 | BC | fishin | NA |
| 2020-04-01 | BC | mining | NA |
| 2020-04-01 | BC | constr | NA |

Comment: jvws2 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(REF_DATE)) %>%
  group_by(GEO, NAICS, Statistics) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "3 month")) %>%
  fill(VALUE) %>%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be

```r
df_mod <- df
df_mod$VALUE <- NA
df_mod[df_mod$REF_DATE == "2020-01-01",1] <- as.Date("2020-04-01")
df_mod[df_mod$REF_DATE == "2020-10-01",1] <- as.Date("2020-07-01")

rbind(df, df_mod)
```

This returns

```r
> rbind(df, df_mod)
      REF_DATE GEO  NAICS VALUE
 1: 2020-01-01  AB fishin    33
 2: 2020-01-01  AB mining   233
 3: 2020-01-01  AB constr    53
 4: 2020-01-01  BC fishin   353
 5: 2020-01-01  BC mining   253
 6: 2020-01-01  BC constr   953
 7: 2020-10-01  AB fishin    33
 8: 2020-10-01  AB mining   293
 9: 2020-10-01  AB constn   343
10: 2020-10-01  BC fishin   633
11: 2020-10-01  BC mining   363
12: 2020-10-01  BC constr   523
13: 2020-04-01  AB fishin    NA
14: 2020-04-01  AB mining    NA
15: 2020-04-01  AB constr    NA
16: 2020-04-01  BC fishin    NA
17: 2020-04-01  BC mining    NA
18: 2020-04-01  BC constr    NA
19: 2020-07-01  AB fishin    NA
20: 2020-07-01  AB mining    NA
21: 2020-07-01  AB constn    NA
22: 2020-07-01  BC fishin    NA
23: 2020-07-01  BC mining    NA
24: 2020-07-01  BC constr    NA
      REF_DATE GEO  NAICS VALUE
```

Comment: Perfect.  This works.. I was over complicating things.  thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if it helped you to solve your problem. :-)